# Spring: handle ambiguous mapping with BadRequest

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm developing a Spring application, and at the moment I'm implementing a search on our customers registry.

A key-pointy of our users request is that the search can be done for  at most  **ONE** of the following parameters  : name **OR** id (can be partial) **OR** shop id (the shop where the customer is registered)
**Searches with more parameters ("more filters" if you prefer) in combination, are not allowed.**

Here i ran  into the problem: I developed a RestController with 1 endpoint handled by 3 different functions like this:

```
@RestController()
    @RequestMapping("v1/customers")
    public class ExampleController {

        /**
        * Search for customer's name (can be partial)
        * @param name
        * @return
        */
        @GetMapping(value="search", params="name")
        public String searchByName(String name) {
            return "search for name";
        }


        /**
        * Search for the customer by id (can be partial)
        * @param name
        * @return
        */
        @GetMapping(value="search", params="id")
        public String searchById(String id) {
            return "search for id";
        }

        /**
        * search for the customer from the shop id where he is registered
        * @param name
        * @return
        */
        @GetMapping(value="search", params="shopId")
        public String searchByShopID(String shopId) {
            return "search for shop";
        }

    }
```

All works fine except for a problem:

The problem is that if the application recive a request with multiple query params like this:

`http://localhost:8080/v1/customers/search?name=bob&shopId=897a`

Spring throw an exception of "Ambiguous Mapping" and return an HTTP 500 status code

How can i handle it? It's possible to handle the case returning an HTTP 400 (and a custom message)? Maybe with something like a "Default mapping".

Comment: Is this something you could do on the front end? As in prevent more than one parameter from being entered by the user?

Comment: If you can't take care of it from the front end, you could use `@Nullable` to make an endpoint that accepts up to all 3 params and returns a 400 error if it has more than one

Comment: I think this is not possible. You may have to create a single method and apply some logic upon some request made.

Comment: @Katie.Sun, I had already managed it on the frontend, but i was looking for a way on the backend too to prevent frontend changes or other future clients to introduce error on the logic.

Comment: Ok. I think the `@Nullable` idea might work, but I can't try it at the moment

Comment: @BunyaminCoskunerI had already tried this way using one method and mapping al parameters to "Optional" but i found this way really confusing and uncomfortable because in real world case i have about 6 possible parameters (instead of 3) and one more parameter that is mandatory only in specific cases (ex: If param1 is present param7 is mandatory else if param2 is present param7 is not mandatory or if param3 is present param7 is not allowed). This led me to mandatory introduce really complex logic just to validate the request

Comment: Thank you all for yours suggestions, I think i found a solution:
@Thank

Comment: Thank you all for yours suggestions, I think i found a solution:
Thank to @GauravRai1512 i read another time the Spring's  documentation, and i noticed that with "params" i can filter for "absent" paramenters too! (i didn't notice at first time) this way `params="!myParam"`

I'm about to post the solution i found.

Comment: @Katie.Sun Unfortunatelly `@Nullable` doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params-- parameter to filter by HTTP parameters. In your case it would be something like:

```
 @GetMapping(value="search",params = "name")
        public String searchByName(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
            return "search for name";
        }

 @GetMapping(value="search",params = "shopId")
    public String searchByShopID(@RequestParam("shopId") String shopId) {
        return "search for shop";
    }
```

Comment: Hi thank for your suggestion but as i wrote in the question (the code part) I already use the "params" parameter (and it works fine) my problem is to handle requests that do not match with any of allowed cases and return an HTTP status 400 (Bad Request)

Answer (score 0):

Thank to @GauravRai1512 i read another time the Spring's  documentation, and i noticed that with "params" i can filter for "absent" paramenters too! (i didn't notice at first time) this way `params="!myParam"`

So i tried to do it this way an it works:

(Let me know your opionion :) )

```
@RestController()
@RequestMapping("v1/customers")
public class ExampleController {

    /**
    * Search for customer's name (can be partial)
    * @param name
    * @return
    */
    @GetMapping(value="search", params={"name", "!id", "!shopId"})
    public String searchByName(String name) {
        return "search for name";
    }


    /**
    * Search for the customer by id (can be partial)
    * @param name
    * @return
    */
    @GetMapping(value="search",  params={"!name", "id", "!shopId"})
    public String searchById(String id) {
        return "search for id";
    }

    /**
    * search for the customer from the shop id where he is registered
    * @param name
    * @return
    */
    @GetMapping(value="search", params={"!name", "!id", "shopId"})
    public String searchByShopID(String shopId) {
        return "search for shop";
    }

    /**
    * Handle invalid reqest
    * @param name
    * @return
    */
    @GetMapping(value="search")
    public String searchByShopID() {
        return "Invalid!";
    }

}
```